# How to change baseUrl dynamically in RTK Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I am new to the RTK Query and I use Redux ToolKit Query to fetch the data.
*Question*: How do I dynamically change the baseUrl in createApi from the input field in App.js file.

I saw similar question here, but the solutions which was provided doesn't work in my case.
[How to dynamicly chane base URL using redux-toolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69568818/how-to-dynamicly-chane-base-url-using-redux-toolkit)

```js
export const WebApi = createApi({ 
    reducerPath: 'API',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001/api' }),
    endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

How to make API call from App.js file, where user can put any kind of API link in the input field and get the result.

something like this:

```
const dynamicUrl = ''
<button className="btn" type="button" onClick={() => refetch(dynamicUrl)}>Fetch Data</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put ***"https://"*** in your   ***baseUrl***     and for endpoints you can pass a string which will be your dynamic urlYou can do like this

```
export const WebApi = createApi({
   reducerPath: 'API',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https:",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUsers: builder.query({
      query: (name) => `/${name}`,
    }),
  }),
});
```

export const { useGetUsersQuery } = usersApi;

In your App.js you can just pass the value

```
const { data, isLoading, refetch } = useGetUsersQuery('//randomuser.me/api');
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in a full url `(starting with http:// or https://)` fetchBaseQuery will skip baseUrl and use the supplied url instead. So you can use the logic that you linked above to just prepend your current baseUrl to the `url` of the query.

Comment: do you mean like this: 
> baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ base Url: '' })

Comment: You can also leave out `baseQuery` completely, or have `baseQuery` pointing to `http://example.com` but have one endpoint go to `https://api-examples.org/foo/bar` instead.

Comment: i'm trying to toggle between local (http://) and prod (https://) at runtime with an admin screen. these options seem to only allow change the URI the first time the `createApi` is called, not after that. Also the handling with http or https as a prefix is harder to do unless the whole API is dynamic. Is there a way to process each time the API call is made, to get the latest endpoint URI?